# Strange Javascript Problem Involving split("/");

Tags: javascript

Okay, so using the following function:

```
function date_add(date, days)
{
  var dim = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31};
  console.log(date.split("/"));
  var date_arr = date.split("/");
  console.log(date_arr);
  ...
}
```

I get the following output at the console screen for date_add("12/08/1990", 1)

```
["12", "08", "1990"]
["2", "08", "1990"]
```

Spending an hour struggling with what could fix this weird problem, on a whim I changed my function to the following:

```
function date_add(date, days)
{
  var dim = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31};
  date = date.split("/");
  console.log(date);
  ...
}
```

Magically, the code works again.  Now don't get me wrong, I'm ecstatic that it worked.  I'm seriously concerned over *why* it worked, though, when the other didn't.  More or less I'm just concerned with why the other didn't work.  Does anyone have a good explanation?

**Edit**: Now they're both broken. >.>

For Tomas, here is the full function:

```
function date_add(date, days)
{
  var dim = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31};
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date.split("/"));
  date_arr = date.split("/");
  console.log(date)
  if (date_arr[0][0] = "0") date_arr[0] = date_arr[0][1];
  if (date_arr[1][0] = "0") date_arr[1] = date_arr[1][1];
  var month = parseInt(date_arr[0]);
  var day   = parseInt(date_arr[1]);
  var year  = parseInt(date_arr[2]);
  console.log(month);
  console.log(day);
  console.log(year);

  if ((year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || year%400 == 0)
    dim[2] = 29;

  day += days;
  while (day < 1)
  {
    month--;
    if (month < 1)
    {
      month = 12;
      year--;
    }
    day += dim[month];
  }

  while (dim[month] < day)
  {
    day -= (dim[month]+1);
    month++;
    if (month > 12)
    {
      month = 0;
      year++;
    }
  }

  return ""+month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
}
```

As for the input for the function, I called this function from the console using `date_add('12/08/1990',1);`

Comment: In what browser was this? It sounds very peculiar... Both FF and Chrome gives me the same result. And of course, they **shold**.

Comment: Dunno what to tell you - I copy-pasted the first code snippet into the firebug console and got the exact same output in both log messages: ` ["12", "08", "1990"]`

Comment: Why not use the built-in `Date` object? Or is "every year's February has exactly 28 days" a required feature?

Comment: @KennyTM it's not required (in fact, once I get the year... which is after this little bit, I change it to 29 if it's a leap year). I'll look at it.  It just seemed so easy...

**Edit** Now they both broke.  Could this be a chrome issue maybe? I'll pull up Firefox.  I'm using Chrome v5.0.375.55, @Sean.

Comment: The code not you've posted does not produce the weird result. Please post more code around this so we can find the problem.

Comment: **Edit Once More** KennyTM, I've managed to get it working using Date() with little to no effort (convert to millis add days in millis, convert to date), but I still find what happened weird.

Comment: Works for me with Chrome 5.0.375.53 (under FC12).

http://xkcd.com/583/

Comment: Yeah, nico, that's what everyone else is telling me, too.  But other people saw it on my computer, too, so I guess I'm not going crazy.  Kind of threw me off a bit.  I had no idea what could make it want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original code is most probably you were not using the second parameter for your `parseInt()` calls, which is to specify the base for which you want to convert to, by default it assumes a 10 base, but when the number starts with zero as in your `08` case, then it assumes its an octal number, so the solution is to use the second parameter in your parseInt calls, like this:

```
var month = parseInt(date_arr[0], 10);
var day   = parseInt(date_arr[1], 10);
var year  = parseInt(date_arr[2], 10);
```

This behaviour have been fixed in last versions of javascript (EcmaScript 5), see this question for more info:

[How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)