# Strange bug in this time calculation script?

Tags: javascript, datetime, math, time, modulus

Basically this script will subtract StartTime from EndTime, using a jQuery plugin the html form is populated with Start and End Time in the format HH:MM, an input field is populated with the result, it works except for one issue:

If Start Time is between 08:00 and 09:59 it just returns strange results - results are 10 hours off to be precise, why?

All other inputs calculate properly!

```
function setValue() { 
var startTime = document.getElementById('ToilA'); 
var endTime = document.getElementById('EndHours'); startTime = startTime.value.split(":"); 
var startHour = parseInt(startTime[0]); 
var startMinutes = parseInt(startTime[1]); 
endTime = endTime.value.split(":"); 
var endHour = parseInt(endTime[0]); 
var endMinutes = parseInt(endTime[1]); 
//var hours, minutes; 
var today = new Date(); 
var time1 = new Date(2000, 01, 01, startHour, startMinutes, 0); 
var time2 = new Date(2000, 01, 01, endHour, endMinutes, 0); var milliSecs = (time2 - time1); 
msSecs = (1000); 
msMins = (msSecs * 60); 
msHours = (msMins * 60); 
numHours = Math.floor(milliSecs/msHours); 
numMins = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours)) / msMins); 
numSecs = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours) - (numMins * msMins))/ msSecs); numSecs = "0" + numSecs; numMins = "0" + numMins; DateCalc = (numHours + ":" + numMins); 

document.getElementById('CalculateHours').value = DateCalc; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you have math problems with the number 8, it's something getting converted into the octal system :)

Numbers starting with `0` [are interpreted as octal numbers in Javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm).

It's no problem from `01..07`, because they are the same in both systems.

But `08` and `09` don't exist in the system, so they return `0`.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) that also provides a solution: Specify the base parameter when doing the parseInt:

```
parseInt("09", 10);  // base 10
```

Comment: When a number begins with a zero, the ECMAScript standard allows an implementation of parseInt() to interpret it as an octal number or a decimal number, so this may work on one browser or not on another.  To fix it for all, use "parseInt(startTime[0],10)" which forces base 10.

Comment: I have one more issue with this code, there is a leading 0 when the minute part is over 10, so it returns something like 11:013 rather that 11:13, can this be fixed with math or will an if statement fix this? Like if number of items > 2, remove first item?

I was going to just do a PHP script to remove this when the form is submitted, but it doesn't look good for the user.

Comment: @user there may be a sneaky clever way to do this more elegantly, but an `if` statement will do the job as well.