# add using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do this

```
var x=$(this).attr('id');
var y = x+1;
```

where x is an integer

but the value I get is x1

How do I do get the 16, if x=15?

Thanks
Jean

Comment: id, should not start with numbers...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var y = parseInt(x) + 1;
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

All the answers so far are missing the [radix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug/850346#850346) parameter

```
var x=parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
var y = x+1;
```

Comment: That's because it's an optional parameter and defaults to 10.

Comment: @Dave: So what value do you think `parseInt('0123')` might return? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt

Comment: @Dave - Yes, optional, defaults to 10, [unless the string starts with 0](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp). It's a deprecated feature, but it still [bites](http://www.kipras.com/a-fact-about-javascript-parseint-that-i-wasnt-aware-of/105) [people](http://www.mgitsolutions.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/). My copy of chrome even does the deprecated thing, using [this test](http://jehiah.cz/archive/javascript-parseint-is-broken).

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks for the article.  Javascript strikes again.  That's *awful*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell JavaScript it's an integer using [parseInt](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm)

```
var y = parseInt(x) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Number("23") + 1);   //24
```

I think you should be using `Number()` instead of `parseInt` because:

```
console.log(Number("23#") + 1);   //NaN
console.log(parseInt("23#") + 1); //24 (I would expect a NaN)
```