# parseInt in Javascript doesn't give back expected value

Tags: javascript, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript parseInt gives very unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342053/javascript-parseint-gives-very-unexpected-results)

Can someone explain why javascript interprets `parseInt(08)` and `parseInt(09)` as zero but does everything right on 01 to 07?

`parseFloat` will give me the correct values for those values, I just couldn't find an answer, why javascript will only do this to the 8s and 9s.

For your information: the leading zeros are from times (hours:minutes).

Please have a look at the following link for a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/NPtzA/3/
There you can see this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Just as a side note: If your whole string is a number (i.e. no suffix), you can just use unary `+` to convert it to an (decimal) integer or float value: `var number = +numberString;` (which is also faster).

Comment: Try `parseInt(08,10)` and `parseInt(09,10)`.

Comment: Yes! You're right, thanks for finding this, now I can see it in the related questions, too!

Comment: Side note 2: http://www.jslint.com/ gives you an error if you don't pass the radix parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` returns 0 because the function is trying to determine the right base  the numerical system it's looking at.

Whether it's a good thing or not, JavaScript numbers with a leading 0 are all considered as Octal which means there is no 08 or 09.

Hope that helps.

**Edit:** Check out my edit of your fiddle which adds `10` parameter to `parseInt` to change the numerical system it uses http://jsfiddle.net/jbrooksuk/NPtzA/5/