# jquery : cannot update progressbar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I have a Websocket server that sends datas from 1 to 1024.

Using JQuery, I am trying to set a progress bar that shows the actual value received.
It does not work...

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";
    // Initialize everything when the window finishes loading
    window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      var message = document.getElementById("message");
      var socket;

        // Create a new connection to websocket server
        socket = new WebSocket("ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080", "echo-protocol");

        // Display messages received from the server
        socket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
          $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", event.data);
          message.textContent = event.data;
        });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      min: 1,
      max: 1024
    });
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", event.data);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="data">
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The fact is that `#message` div displays values with no problems, but i am not able to update the JQuery progressbar...
Any idea would be welcome...

Comment: What's inside `event.data` when you try to update? And why you initialize it with `event.data`. It isn't defined there, isn't it?

Comment: Interesting comment : `event.data` is equal to data send from ws (as shown by `message.textContent = event.data;` in `#message`. Event.data is not defined but updates successfully `#message`

Comment: I never used jQuery UI progressbar till now, but maybe you have to convert your data to `int` like you set it with `min` and `max`. Try `parseInt(event.data, 10);` and make a `console.log(event.data);` before to verify the value.

Comment: `parseInt(event.data, 10);` seems to work. Can you explain further and write an answer ? i will aprove

Comment: I've made an answer for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `event.data` value is of type `string` e.g. `'157'` and not a `number` like e.g. `157`. To find it out try:

```
console.log(typeof event.data); // => string
```

To parse it to type `number`you have to use `parseInt`.
`parseInt` has two parameters, first one is the value to parse and second one with value `10` is "to make sure the string is interpreted as base 10 (decimal)." For more Information read also this: [Javascript parseInt gives very unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342053/javascript-parseint-gives-very-unexpected-results)

```
var intValue = parseInt(event.data, 10);
console.log(typeof intValue); // => number
```

Documentation for `parseInt`'s parameters:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

To make your code even better you can also check if the value is between `min` and `max`. I mean between your defined bounds `0` (option `min` is not in documentation) and `1024` like so:

```
var min = 0;
var max = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "max");

if (intValue >= min && intValue <= max) {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", intValue);
}
```

Comment: You are a master, you saved my day. I really love this site and people with real skills here. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Not a problem ;) But mention, that `option`is not defined for the progressbar, it's always `0`. See here: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Not `option`, I meant option `min`... It's not defined for progress bar. Only `max` can be set.

Comment: So now i agree ! i will update my code according to this and according to your advices. Thanks again