# How do I convert an string to an Int which is came from the input of an button

Tags: javascript, html, string, int

I need to convert the string from my `innerHTML` which are received by an button click (I'm making an calculator) 
If needed here is my JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
// your code here
var counter = document.getElementById("scherm");
    var optellen = document.getElementById("1");
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "=", "C"]

    // maak for loop voor buttons 
    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", screen);
    }

    //optellen.addEventListener("click", screen); //+ string + sting aan het einde als je wilt gaan uitrekenen doe je parseInt()

    function screen() {
        if( operators.indexOf(this.innerHTML) != -1)
        {   

            if( operators.indexOf(this.innerHTML) == 5)
            {
                document.getElementById("scherm").innerHTML="";
            }

        }
        else
        {

            counter.innerHTML += this.innerHTML;
        }

        console.log(this.innerHTML);

        //if(counter.innerHTML == this.inner)
        //counter.innerHTML = buttons.innerHTML;
        //
    }
```

};

as requested HTML:
`<div id="rekenmachine">
    <header><p id="scherm"></p></header>
    <section id="knoppen">
        <div class="row">
            <button value="1">1</button>
            <button value="2" class="pos">2</button>
            <button value="3" class="pos">3</button>
            <button value="+" class="pos">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button value="">4</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">5</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">6</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button value="">7</button>
            <button class="pos">8</button>
            <button class="pos">9</button>
            <button class="pos">*</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button value="">C</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">0</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">=</button>
            <button value="" class="pos">/</button>
        </div>
    </section>`

Comment: Could you show html too ?

Comment: also do remember the [base in `parseInt()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342079/3419997)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
parseInt("10");
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

(you should do something like: parseInt(counter.innerHTML))

```
 else {
     var result;
     if(counter.innerHTML != "") { 
         result = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
      } else {
          result = 0;
      } 
     result += parseInt(this.innerHTML); 
     counter.innerHTML = result; }
```

Comment: got it like this now: `document.getElementById("scherm").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("scherm").innerHTML);` but it only inserts a NaN infront of the numbers

Comment: Thats not the correct approuch ;). Make sure the innerHTML is parsable. (Wich means only numerical values are present). It would be a lot easyer to explain in our language (Dutch), wich is against the rules :). You parse the values and calculate with them, if then put in another div (innerHTML), they are automaticcaly interpreted as a String again.

Comment: Is it possible to add your HTML to your post?

Comment: That really would be as its still a bit confusing to me the problem also is that with that line of code they dont add up to each other anymore. This site really needs an chat function

Comment: Okay, try something like this: In yourelse
        {

            counter.innerHTML += this.innerHTML;
        } 
Chane to this: else {
var result = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
result += parseInt(this.innerHTML);
this.innerHTML = result;
}

Comment: Now my buttons change to NaN

Comment: Got it like this now `else
   {
    var getal = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
    counter.innerHTML += this.innerHTML;
    
   }
   
   console.log(this.innerHTML);
   console.log(getal);` and it shows the int in the logs now but can i use it to calculate?

Comment: Good sign :). Now I see something: Your div id="scherm" is an empty div. You should first check if it's empty. I'm guessing you're in school right now? ;)

else {var result; if(counter.innerHTML != "") { result = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);} else {result = 0;} result += parseInt(this.innerHTML); this.innerHTML = result; }

Comment: edited the answer :). Look above. please accept this as an answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Parsing function. Parsing will stop if hits a character than doesn't recognise. If parsing stop at first symbol then it returns NaN

```
parseInt("1") = 1
parseInt("1a") = 1
parseInt("a1") = NaN
```

Type changing.

Unary plus

```
+"1" = 1
+"1.231" = 1.231
+"1a" = NaN
+"a1" = NaN
```

Bitwise NOT

```
~~"1" = 1
~~"1.231" = 1
~~"a1" = 0
~~"1a" = 0
~~"a" = 0
```

Multiplication operator

```
"1" * 1 = 1
"1a" * 1 = NaN
"a1" * 1 = NaN
"a" * 1 = NaN
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your answer.