# Passing a numeric variable to jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am having a bit of a problem with the following:

```
function loadContent(id) {
     $("#featuredDiv").load("featuredDiv.php?list="+id);
     );
}
```

It all works fine when opening the URL with an ID of 21012011 like:

```
javascript:loadContent(28012011)
```

but when 04022011 is the id (`javascript:loadContent(28012011)`), it seems to change the number to 1057801.

I need the number to be passed through exactly as it is reading the page from a database.
Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have an extra `);` in there

Answer (score 5):

That is because `04022011` is parsed by Javascript as an [octal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug).

Wrap the ID in quotes at all times and it will work.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit thick.
I tried: 
$("#featuredDiv").load("featuredDiv.php?list="+'id');

but it didn't work

Comment: @Oak the value of `id` must be in quotes when you pass it: `loadContent('28012011');` But don't quote `id` itself

Comment: Thanks Pekka, you're a ledgend!
I can sleep tonight now :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the difference between decimal and octal notation.

For historical reasons, which have nothing to do with utility to modern programmers, a sequence of numbers starting with a `0` and containing no `8` or `9` characters is interpreted as an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/octal_number).  This means that it is treated as being in base-8, rather than base-10.

The octal `04022011` is `1057801` in decimal notation.

You can fix this by wrapping your number in quote marks (e.g. `javascript:loadContent("28012011")`): this will cause it to be interpreted as a string and passed directly into your URL.

**However** You appear to be using `<a href="javascript:...">` links.  This is **bad** practice.  Look into an introduction to jQuery (e.g. [jqfundamentals.com](http://jqfundamentals.com/)) to see optimal ways to bind actions to elements and events.

Comment: Thanks Lonesome, 

I will read up on the JQfundamentals right now.

Comment: Wow, what an essay! :) +1 for detailed and verbose background.