# Javascript Rounding to the nearest 2 decimal (however 5 rounds down)

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

All my values are being returned from the server as 3 decimal places. I need to round to the nearest 10, 2 decimal places, ex. decimal(18,2) from decimal(18,3). The catch is that when it's a 5, it needs to round down.

I need to do this in JavaScript :D

I can not guarantee 3 decimal places will be returned, that is the maximum.

```
ex. 4.494 -> 4.49

**ex. 4.495 -> 4.49**

ex. 4.496 -> 4.50
```

Comment: have you tried anything? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round, `if(Math.abs(num) === 5)` + `Math.floor` should cover your case of the number being 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want special rounding only where the last digit is 5, so test for that and round those cases differently:

```
function myRound(n) {

  // If ends in .nn5, round down
  if (/\.\d\d5$/.test(''+n)) {
    n = Math.floor(n*100)/100;
  }

  // Apply normal rounding
  return n.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(myRound(4.494));  // 4.49
console.log(myRound(4.495));  // 4.49
console.log(myRound(4.496));  // 4.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create your own custom round function? check out [Is it ok to overwrite the default Math.round javascript functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386280/is-it-ok-to-overwrite-the-default-math-round-javascript-functionality)

Given the solution in the above post, you might modify it slightly like this:

```js
Number.prototype.round = function(precision) {
    var numPrecision = (!precision) ? 0 : parseInt(precision, 10);
    var numBig = this * Math.pow(10, numPrecision);
    var roundedNum;
    if (numBig - Math.floor(numBig) == 0.5)
        roundedNum = (Math.round(numBig) + 1) / Math.pow(10, numPrecision);
    else
        roundedNum = Math.round(numBig) / Math.pow(10, numPrecision);

    return roundedNum;
};

var n = 2.344;
var x = n.round(2);

alert(x);
```