# function "New Date()" doing something strange

Tags: jquery, date

I have noticed that the jQuery function New Date() does something odd. I have already found a way to work around it so I don't need help. I just want to understand why it is doing this.

I have a function doing the following:

```
new Date(parseInt(y),parseInt(m)-1,parseInt(d))
```

the actual numbers are: `y= '2011', m= '07', d='01'`. This works fine, it returns the date 1/7/2011. But when I use `m= '08'` it returns "Wed Dec 01 2010"

I tracked it down to the parseInt function. Somehow `parseInt('07') = 7` but `parseInt('08') = 0`
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: "jQuery function New Date()"........ **/facedesk**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First New Date() is not a jQuery function, but plain JavaScript.

Unfortunately, JavaScript borrowed a lot from the language C, in which you write octal numbers by prepending a zero in front of it. Octal numbers a numbers which go from 0 to 7.

What you have to do, and is best practice, is to say you have decimal numbers, not octal.

Always give the radix: parseInt(y, 10), so you code will be:

```
new Date(parseInt(y, 10),parseInt(m, 10)-1,parseInt(d, 10))
```

More info about parseInt:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 5):

Try `new Date(parseInt(y,10),parseInt(m,10)-1,parseInt(d,10))`

`parseInt` uses base 8 if the string starts with a zero.