# Javascript zero paddedstring to int

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

I have the following numbers:

01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12

These are a string I want to convert them to an int. So 02 becomes 2. I have `parseInt('02')` but this returns `int 0`

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome, I get 2: http://jsfiddle.net/BSpU6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the radix: `parseInt('02', 10)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell javascript the type of number you're trying to convert.

```
parseInt('02', 10); // number is base 10
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) for more details.