# javascript problem with parseint

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

I am trying to parse an integer number.

```
a = parseInt("0005")  <- gives 5
a = parseInt("0008")  <- gives 0
```

Can someone explain what's happening? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. This solved the problem. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it and close off the questions.

Answer (score 2):

When `parseInt` has a leading 0 and a radix parameter isn't specified, it assumes you want to convert the number to octal.  Instead you should always specify a radix parameter like so:

```
a = parseInt("0008", 10) // => 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers starting with 0 are parsed as octal by `parseInt`, unless you specify a radix to use.

You can force parseInt to parse as decimal by doing

```
a = parseInt("0008", 10)
```