# What do you think parseInt("08") will return?

Tags: javascript, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Surprisingly it returns `0`. Why? and what's the (proper) solution to get correct results?

Comment: @Sorrow: Except that it's for Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a radix:

```
var x = parseInt("08", 10);
```

Some JavaScript implementations add a third numeral system to the two defined by the standard (decimal, the default; and hex, prefixed with `0x`): Octal, prefixed with `0`. This is *non-standard* but acknowledged as common in the [latest spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Since `8` is not a valid octal digit, `parseInt` stops there, returning the value `0`.

By explicitly using a radix, you tell `parseInt` not to try to figure out what numeral system is being used but instead to use the one you specify. Your instinct when typing `parseInt` should *always* be to specify the radix; not doing so leaves you open to oddities.

Answer (score 1):

"08" mean 8 based number. You should specify second argument.

```
 parseInt("08", 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@T.J. gave a great explanation for the behaviour you see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410009/what-do-you-think-parseint08-will-return/6410025#6410025). Another way to parse a number string is to use unary `+`:

```
var num = +"08";
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2012-Exploring-Javascript-s-parseInt-And-parseFloat-Functions.htm:

> Strings that start with "0" are assumed to be base8 (octal).

Answer (score 0):

From MDC - [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.

And the example:

> parseInt("08"); // 0, '8' is not an octal digit.

That is, since no radix was passed in and the string begins with `0` octal is assumed. Since `8` is not an octal digit it cannot be parsed.

Solution? Always provide a radix parameter:

```
parseInt("08", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it through jslint, it'll squawk at you for not including the radix parameter. Yes, the radix is optional, but probably should be included every time. A number starting with 0 is assumed to be octal unless otherwise specified.

```
var foo = parseInt("08", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number prefixed with "0" is octal number. `8` is invalid octal number. so the result is 0