# parseInt("08") returns 0

Tags: javascript, parsing, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

I've been working on a javascript function, setting date objects by declaring the year, month & date. However, when the month has a value of `08` or `09`, `0` is returned when using `parseInt()`. See below:

```
parseInt("01") //returns 1
parseInt("02") //returns 2
parseInt("03") //returns 3
parseInt("04") //returns 4
parseInt("05") //returns 5
parseInt("06") //returns 6
parseInt("07") //returns 7
parseInt("08") //returns 0?
parseInt("09") //returns 0?
parseInt("10") //returns 10
```

I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/GhkEf/

Why does `parseInt("08")` and `parseInt("09")` return `0`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410009/what-do-you-think-parseint08-will-return?rq=1

Comment: Read the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt This issue is well documented

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Ahh of course! Friday afternoon hiccup! Thanks for your responses

Comment: I voted to reopen because Unlike [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior) this question is more well suited at people who don't already know that this is due to octal notation

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's because numbers started with 0 are considered to be octal. And 08 is a wrong number in octal.

Use `parseInt('09', 10);` instead.

Comment: This occur just on IE8.

Answer (score 5):

It's being parsed as an octal number. Use the `radix` parameter in `parseInt`.

`parseInt('08', 10);`

An update: As of ES5, browsers should **not** have this bug. Octal literals require to be in the form `0o12` to be considered Octal numbers. `08` by default is now considered a decimal number in ES5, however, all browsers may not support this yet, so you should continue to pass the `radix` parameter to `parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by including the radix, e.g.:

```
parseInt("08", 10); // outputs 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a radix of ten:

```
parseInt("08", 10);
```

Some implementations default to octal.