# Modify parseInt method: Javascript

Tags: javascript, parseint

I do not want use each and every time `parseInt('08', 10)` for each string to integer conversion,

Can we modify `parseInt` method, so that i can use only `parseInt('08')` instead of `parseInt('08', 10)`.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of modifying the built-in function `parseInt`, you can define your own function like this:

```
function prseInt(n)
{
    return parseInt(n, 10);
}
```

And replace all the occurences of `parseInt(n, 10)` you have used in your app with `prseInt(n)`.

#### Fine, if you still wanna redefine, you can do this:

```
var origParseInt = parseInt;
parseInt = function(n) {
     return origParseInt(n, 10);
}
```

And it works!

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKKwv/

Comment: That is the simple way, but i donot want to introduce any new method for this, is that possible to modify built-in function to make it happen?

Comment: Thats great, until another developer comes along and thinks they've found a typo and correct all your `prseInt` to `parseInt`

Comment: You cannot modify the built-in function. But yeah, possible, will update in the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Get the *what*?

Comment: Lol, guides on functions used, why used, etc? Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - hahahaha, I see you're not jaded by this industry yet. Give it time. In an ideal world, every new developer understands everything about the project they've been assigned to. In the real world, its a ball of mud thats been developed by many hands over many years. Nothing is well documented, there are no concrete guidlines.

Comment: @Jamiec, I agree "In the real world, its a ball of mud thats been developed by many hands over many years."

Comment: @Jamiec Agreed with you. And also updated the answer with a demo! :)

Comment: @Guys, Nobody's feeling, Wouldn't my question helps for other guys? :) :)

Comment: @Niks It sure does help. We are still searching. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use simply a `+` operator in front of your string, to perform a type coercion (and no need to call `parseInt()`)

```
var str = "08";
var num = +str;

console.log(num, typeof num);  // 8, number
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt(xx)` (ie, without the radix parameter) will work perfectly fine 99% of the time, what it will do is attempt to guess what base you are after.

For a single number like `8` it will correctly guess basse10 and give you integer 8. The problem is a string like `08` it will guess what you want is octal, and converting ["08" to octal returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410009/what-do-you-think-parseint08-will-return).

You should **ALWAYS** be providing the radix parameter whenever  using `parseInt`.

Comment: Yeh..you are abs'ly right, but can't we modify built-in method, so we could use everytime parseInt(value) instead of parseInt(value, radix)?

Comment: You *can* use `parseInt(value)` as I explained - so long as you understand the behaviour. If the `value` is ever going to be prefixed `0` it will convert it to Octal. And no, you cannot modify a built-in method, otherwise it wouldnt be "built-in".