# Number with leading zero in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Try this:

```js
var num = 040;
console.log(num); // 32
```

Since when is 40 = 32?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) (even though it is not a bug, just  a gotcha)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: I have accepted your answer before, did so now again. Strange that it didn't take the first time. Thanks again Levu.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a leading zero, the number is interpreted as octal and `4 * 8 = 32`.

Answer (score 23):

#### TL;DR

It's being treated as octal (base 8) because of the leading `0`, just like a leading `0x` would make it hex (base 16). This has a long and tortured history and is no longer how octal numbers are written in modern JavaScript. In modern JavaScript using strict mode, the "legacy" octal format is a syntax error; octal numbers are written with an `0o` prefix.

#### History

Early on (in the initial language from Netscape and the first and second ECMAScript specifications), a leading `0` on a numeric literal officially meant *octal* (base 8), just as a leading `0x` means hexadecimal (base 16):

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit
    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
```

E.g., `10`, `012`, and `0xA` were all ways of writing the decimal number ten. This is in keeping with some other languages with syntax similar to JavaScript (C, C++, Java, ...), but it's highly confusing.

As of ECMAScript 3, that form of octal literal was downgraded to an optional extension, and decimal integer literals were changed so that they can't have leading zeros (unless the implementation includes the extension):

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits(opt)
```

But [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) forbade doing that in strict-mode:

> A conforming implementation, when processing [strict mode code (see
>   10.1.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), must not extend the syntax of *NumericLiteral* to include *OctalIntegerLiteral* as described in [B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1).

[ECMAScript 6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals) (ECMAScript 2015) introduces *BinaryIntegerLiteral* and *OctalIntegerLiteral*, so now we have more coherent literals:

- *BinaryIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0b` or `0B`.
- *OctalIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0o` or `0O`.
- *HexIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0x` or `0X`.

The old *OctalIntegerLiteral* extension has been renamed to *LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral*, which is still allowed in non-strict mode.

**Conclusion**

Therefore, if you want to parse a number in base 8, use the `0o` or `0O` prefixes (not supported by old browsers), or use `parseInt`.

And if you want to be sure your numbers will be parsed in base 10, remove leading zeros, or use `parseInt`.

**Examples**

- <s>`010`</s>

  - In strict mode (requires ECMAScript 5), it's a syntax error.
  - In non-strict mode, it may be a syntax error or return `8` (implementation dependent).
- `0o10`, `0O10`

  - Before ECMAScript 6, they're syntax errors.
  - In ECMAScript 6, they return `8`.
- `parseInt('010', 8)`

  - It returns `8`.
- `parseInt('010', 10)`

  - It returns `10`.

If you're interested, you can find the current living specification [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/), and historical versions [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Because the `0` prefix indicates an octal number (base 8).