# Understanding number bases in javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leading zero in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505033/leading-zero-in-javascript)

Given you have the following JavaScript snippet:

```
<script>
   var x = 013;
   console.log(x);
</script>
```

Why is it that Firebug prints `11`?

Comment: does it interpret that as octal?

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2c_Variables%2c_and_Literals#Integers

Comment: The leading 0 means it's in [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript supports the same convention for numeric constants as C and Java (et al), so the leading zero makes that an octal constant. ("13" in base 8 is 8 + 3, or 11.)

Comment: Also, Pointy is always right.

Comment: @karim79: That goes without saying. Pointy's a rock star!

Comment: Gee whiz you guys.  I'm too old to be a rock star :-)

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - I am a rockstar too!

Comment: @karim79: Yes you are, but you were a mega-rockstar when you were Simpsonized. ;)

Comment: The Red Hot Chili Peppers are old too and still rock stars.... at least for me ;) You are never to old to be a rock star!

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - I de-simponified myself in the hope that a more personal photo would gain me more rep. How wrong I was. :(

Comment: @karim79: You have to unicornify!

Comment: @Felix Kling - True! Oh how I'm looking forward to my T-shirt!

Comment: @karim79: Me too :) Will be a nice Christmas present...

Answer (score 3):

Its octal value. So it 1*8^1 + 3*8^0=11

Answer (score 2):

Because you've specified an octal number, but it displays its decimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting it as octal. Any number that begins in zero is interpreted as an octal (base 8) literal, and octal 13 = 8*1+3 = 11 decimal.

Also, good title.

Answer (score 1):

It is being interpreted as base 8.  And 013 in base 8 is 11 decimal.

In javascript, constant numbers that begin with 0dd or -0dd and are not 0xdd or -0xdd are interpreted as octal (base 8).

You can see it described in the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262%20edition%205.1,%20June%202011.pdf) on page 231.

Answer (score 1):

`013` is an *octal* constant - it's interpreted in base 8. 1·8 + 3·1 = 8 + 3 = **11**