# Javascript math error with leading zeroes

Tags: javascript, addition

I am an amateur programmer writing simple HTML/Javascript programs, and I recently ran into something I can't explain. I have a small program that sets the starting and ending time for an appointment. The format is HHMMSS for both. I hard-coded the start times I needed, for example 103000 or 123000, and then wrote a line of code to add 10000 to get the end time. This worked fine until I tried 073000 + 10000. The result, instead of being 083000 (or at least 83000), ended up being 40208.

I would write the problem off as an issue with the leading 0, but 093000 + 10000 = 103000, which is what I would expect. What is going on with 073000 + 10000 = 40208?

I fixed the program a different way, but I am stumped by this. Many thanks for any explanation you can provide.

Here is some simple code from w3schools that produces 40208 as the addition result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = 073000 + 10000;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to `"use strict"`, because otherwise `073000 = 30208`

Comment: elclanrs, you could expand your comment into an answer and the the poster know why that is occuring.  I don't know or I'd the comment myself.

Comment: @SteveMitcham, feel free, feeling lazy here, and didn't find the common dups.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505033/leading-zero-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers with a leading `0` are octal numbers in the same way numbers with leading `0x` are hexadecimal numbers:

```
01 = 1
02 = 2
...
07 = 7
010 = 8
011 = 9
```

Normally `09` would cause a syntax error because `9` is not an octal digit (in the same way that `e` is not a decimal digit). But apparently most browsers these days auto detect it as decimal instead of raising an error.

---

Note: In strict mode using octal syntax (starting a number with leading `0` causes syntax error because octal syntax isn't part of the ECMAscript standard.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I had no idea what the problem was.