# Why JavaScript treats a number as octal if it has a leading zero

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 010;
console.log(x); //8
```

JS engine convert the number `x` to octal number. Why it happens? How can I prevent it?

Comment: @Andy - 10, not 8.  He's asking why prefixing a number with a 0 makes it assume it's octal.  I don't blame him for asking.

Comment: A literal numeric value that starts with a 0 is always interpreted as an octal value.

Comment: Hah, yeah, I didn't ask that question properly. I know why it logs it as octal, I just wondered if 10 was the expected output from the OP.

Comment: This is a non-standard practice forbidden in strict mode. See [Leading zero in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354557/1529630)

Comment: If we prefix a number with 0x then it will convert the number to Hexadecimal as well

Comment: On not strict mode, it will convert to octal if it CAN, `010 === 08` that will log true. Now you know why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number with leading zero in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505033/number-with-leading-zero-in-javascript)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354557/1529630) answers the question, but the question is not exactly a duplicate, so I include a copy of my answer.

**History**

The problem is that decimal integer literals can't have leading zeros:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits(opt)
```

However, ECMAScript 3 allowed (as an optional extension) to parse literals with leading zeros in base 8:

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit
    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
```

But [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) forbade doing that in strict-mode:

> A conforming implementation, when processing [strict mode code (see
>   10.1.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), must not extend the syntax of *NumericLiteral* to include *OctalIntegerLiteral* as described in [B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1).

[ECMAScript 6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals) introduces *BinaryIntegerLiteral* and *OctalIntegerLiteral*, so now we have more coherent literals:

- *BinaryIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0b` or `0B`.
- *OctalIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0o` or `0O`.
- *HexIntegerLiteral*, prefixed with `0x` or `0X`.

The old *OctalIntegerLiteral* extension has been renamed to *LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral*, which is still allowed in non-strict mode.

**Conclusion**

Therefore, if you want to parse a number in base 8, use the `0o` or `0O` prefixes (not supported by old browsers), or use `parseInt`.

And if you want to be sure your numbers will be parsed in base 10, remove leading zeros, or use `parseInt`.

**Examples**

- `010`

  - In strict mode (requires ECMAScript 5), it throws.
  - In non strict mode, it may throw or return `8` (implementation dependent).
- `0o10`, `0O10`

  - Before ECMAScript 6, they throw.
  - In ECMAScript 6, they return `8`.
- `parseInt('010', 8)`

  - It returns `8`.
- `parseInt('010', 10)`

  - It returns `10`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because some JavaScript engines interpret leading zeros as octal number literals. It is defined in an appendix of [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1).

However, in strict mode, the conforming implementations must not implement that - see [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) again:

> A conforming implementation, when processing strict mode code (see
>   10.1.1), must not extend the syntax of NumericLiteral to include OctalIntegerLiteral as described in B.1.1.

Because of this ambiguity, it's better not to use leading zeros.

Comment: It's not the syntax of JS literals. It's a discouraged non-standard extension explicitly forbidden in strict mode.

Comment: Right :) Never noticed that. Made me give +1 to the question. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 2):

JS treat numbers with leading zeros as octal only if they valid octal, if not then it treat it as decimal. To prevent this not use leading zeros in your source code

```js
console.log(010, 10, +"010")

if (021 < 019) console.log('Paradox');
```

or use `strict mode` to not allow using leading zeros

```js
'use strict'

if (021 < 019) console.log('Paradox');
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Decimals with leading zeros are not allowed in strict mode."