# Why is 0700/100 equal to 4.48 and 0900/100 equal to 9 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(0700/100) // result: 4.48
console.log(0900/100) // result: 9
```

I was learning vue by creating a calculator app and was using an array to store the variable. When I was testing it by entering 0s before the actual operand, I got confused by the above behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `0700` starts with a zero, JS treats it as an octal (base-8) number. `0900` couldn't be octal, so JS treats it as regular decimal (base-10) number.

`0700 octal = 448 decimal`, so `0700 (octal) / 100 (decimal) = 4.48`

Comment: I suppose, real question is why 0900 is interpreted as decimal instead of throwing error about broken octal...

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski There's some interesting context and history in this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003770/why-javascript-treats-a-number-as-octal-if-it-has-a-leading-zero. Short version is use strict mode and this goes away.

Comment: I see, thanks a bunch sir. Can I ask why it treats 0700 as an octal just because it starts with a 0. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski Because that’s what has been specified since the beginning of JavaScript. Modern features don’t use this behavior.

Comment: I see, weird but thanks a lot

Comment: Does decimal number have the number 10 as a single digit? no. Octal doesn't either. The largest single digit in Octal is 7. The numbers go from 0-7 and not from 0-8. I fixed your example :)

Answer (score 0):

When you put a 0 before a number, js casts it to octal, which is equal to 448. But 0900 contains 9 so it cannot be octal, thus it will be equal to 900.

Comment: It doesn’t “cast” it to octal, it _parses_ it as octal.