# How to convert base 2 integer with leading zeros to a string javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, binary

I'm given an array of integers such as:

```js
const vals=[
  00100,
  11110,
  00100101,
  ...
]
```

and I need to simply make each value iterable maintaining the position of the leading zeros. My first thought was to turn them into strings, but JavaScript wants to use base 10 and nothing that I have tried will change this. And when I try parsing it back to base 2, the leading zeros are all swapped around:

```
let testNum = 00100; // saves as 64
testNum = parseInt(testNum, 10); // using radix 2 returns NaN
testNum = testNum.toString(2); // 1000000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Number literals starting with 0 are treated as base 8 (octals)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6505033/215552) (in non-strict mode, but since you're supposedly not getting errors, I'm assuming you're not in strict mode).

Comment: Note that [`parseInt`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), or preferrably [`Number.parseInt`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt), accepts a _string_ and returns a _number_, and [`Number.prototype.toString`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) works with a _number_ as its `this` and returns a _string_. Numbers in different bases are supposed to be _strings_.

Comment: This still doesn't help me convert `00100` to `"00100"`. I'm aware of the octet "bug" and how to work around it when dealing with base 10 numbers or other numbers that can otherwise be converted to other bases. But `00100` doesn't convert to base 2. 

And  you're right @SebastianSimon sorry about that. I just typed those out as examples.

Comment: @JoshCarvin You can’t reliably “convert” the number to the string. You have to supply a string to begin with.

Comment: In strict mode you can't even work with the array as it stands. Is this homework?

Comment: So there's is no possible solution, using javascript, to get the string `"00100"` from the initial value of `00100`?

Comment: @pilchard no it's not homework. And the array isn't exactly what's provided. I just typed that up as a brief example. It's just pseudo code. The array is more complicated than this question warrants.

Comment: but it has a range of numbers some that start with 0, and there's no way of getting it with those values already cast as strings?

Comment: `(00100 / 16).toString(2).padStart(5, '0')` :) Just kidding of course, that wouldn't work with `11110`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I thought about this. But what if the lengths of the values aren't 5?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to somehow know how many digits they were originally, since JavaScript doesn't store that info: `00100.toString(8) // '100'`

Comment: @HereticMonkey gotcha. So They just have to be strings to start with, then. Or they have to have a fixed length. Thanks!