# Javscripts prints 1024 when I console.log(02000)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with an array of numbers

```
let nums = [02000, 02000, 02200, 02020,02002]
```

The problem is when I `console.log(nums)` it prints out `[1024,1024,1152,1040,1026]`.

Why is it changing my numbers?

Comment: Your "numbers" have a leading zero.  JavaScript interprets these to be octal numbers, not decimal.  https://decimaltobinary.pro/_octal__2000_in_decimal_

Comment: it isn't. [Those are the same numbers as per the language specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#numbers). Just like how `16`, `0b10000`, `020`, `0xF`, and `0.16e2` are all the exact same number. Just written as decimal, binary, octal, hexadecimal, and scientific numbers respectively.

Comment: Extended answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505033/number-with-leading-zero-in-javascript/28354557#28354557

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, [Numeric Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#numeric_literals) have their own lexical grammar.

When numbers start with a leading `0`, it *may* be interpreted as an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

> Note that decimal literals can start with a zero (`0`) followed by another decimal digit, but if all digits after the leading `0` **are smaller than 8, the number is interpreted as an *octal number*.**