# Behavior difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()

Tags: javascript, parsing

Why is this behavior difference between `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`?

I have a string that contains `08` in it.

When I write this code:

```
alert(hfrom[0]);
alert(parseInt(hfrom[0]));
alert(parseFloat(hfrom[0]));
```

The following output is generated:

```
08
0
8
```

Why does `parseInt` and `parseFloat` return two different results in this case?

Comment: Check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900857/alertparseint09-shows-me-0-why   It is because parseInt assume 08 to be parsed as Octal base as it starts with 0

Comment: Running on jsfilddle in chrome I get `8` for both functions: http://jsfiddle.net/nqNvw/

Comment: @gideon, that's because you passed in numbers which were already converted to base-10 integers. If you pass in *strings* it behaves differently. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nqNvw/1/ (this is definitely a wtfjs kind of thing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) assumes the base of your number according to the first characters in the string. If it begins with `0x` it assumes base 16 (hexadecimal). Otherwise, if it begins with `0` it assumes base 8 (octal). Otherwise it assumes base 10.

You can specify the base as a second argument:

```
alert(parseInt(hfrom[0], 10)); // 8
```

From MDN (linked above):

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>   (hexadecimal). If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight
>   (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations
>   deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this
>   reason always specify a radix when using parseInt. If the input string
>   begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

Comment: Also see the **Examples** section on that page.

Comment: Not anymore? They fixed it? parseInt('010') now prints 10

Comment: Looks like they fixed it to some extent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22140772/1364747

Comment: @Teddy Correct. This answer from six years ago is no longer relevant, but the question doesn't make as much sense today either since nobody should see the behavior the OP did anymore.

Comment: True. I specifically Googled for parseInt vs parseFloat today and this question was in the top few links.

Comment: @Teddy I think the title is an unfortunate choice, since it really has nothing to do with `parseFloat`. I closed it as a duplicate just now, but I'm not sure if that affects search rankings. Maybe the title should be edited too or something.

Answer (score 2):

you should always include the radix param with `parseInt()` ex `parseInt('013', 10)` otherwise  it can convert it to a different numeric base:

```
parseInt('013') === 11
parseInt('013', 10) === 13
parseInt('0x13') === 19
```