# difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behavior difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat)

```
var box  = $('.box'),
fontSize = parseInt(box.css('font-size'), 10) + 5;

 $('button').on('click', function() {
  box.animate({fontSize: fontSize});
});
```

//..

```
 var box  = $('.box'),
 fontSize = parseFloat(box.css('font-size'), 10) + 5;

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    box.animate({fontSize: fontSize})
});
```

what the difference between..

```
**fontSize = parseInt(box.css('font-size'), 10);**

**fontSize = parseFloat(box.css('font-size'), 10);**
```

and and why should put 10 as a context..Please Help?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat

Comment: Also this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FFunctions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_Functions

Answer (score 57):

> JavaScript provides two methods for converting non-number primitives
>   into numbers: parseInt() and parseFloat() . As you may have guessed,
>   the former converts a value into an integer whereas the latter
>   converts a value into a floating-point number.

Any number literal contained in a string is also converted correctly, so the string "0xA" is properly converted into the number 10. However, the string "22.5" will be converted to 22 , because the decimal point is an invalid character for an integer. Some examples:

> var iNum1 = parseInt("1234blue"); //returns 1234
>
> var iNum2 = parseInt("0xA"); //returns 10
>
> var iNum3 = parseInt("22.5"); //returns 22
>
> var iNum4 = parseInt("blue"); //returns NaN

The parseInt() method also has a radix mode, allowing you to convert strings in binary, octal, hexadecimal, or any other base into an integer. The radix is specified as a second argument to parseInt() , so a call to parse a hexadecimal value looks like this:

> var iNum1 = parseInt("AF", 16); //returns 175
>
> Of course, this can also be done for binary, octal, and even decimal
>   (which is the default mode):
>
> var iNum1 = parseInt("10", 2); //returns 2
>
> var iNum2 = parseInt("10", 8); //returns 8
>
> var iNum2 = parseInt("10", 10); //returns 10

If decimal numbers contain a leading zero, it’s always best to specify the radix as 10 so that you won’t accidentally end up with an octal value. For example:

> var iNum1 = parseInt("010"); //returns 8
>
> var iNum2 = parseInt("010", 8); //returns 8
>
> var iNum3 = parseInt("010", 10); //returns 10
>
> In this code, both lines are parsing the string "010" into a number.
>   The first line thinks that the string is an octal value and parses it
>   the same way as the second line (which specifies the radix as 8). The
>   last line specifies a radix of 10, so iNum3 ends up equal to 10.

Another difference when using parseFloat() is that the string must represent a floating-point number in decimal form, not octal or hexadecimal. This method ignores leading zeros, so the octal number 0908 will be parsed into 908 , and the hexadecimal number 0xA will return NaN because x isn’t a valid character for a floating-point number. There is also no radix mode for parseFloat() .

> Some examples of using parseFloat() :
>
> var fNum1 = parseFloat("1234blue"); //returns 1234
>
> var fNum2 = parseFloat("0xA"); //returns 0
>
> var fNum3 = parseFloat("22.5"); //returns 22.5
>
> var fNum4 = parseFloat("22.34.5"); //returns 22.34
>
> var fNum5 = parseFloat("0908"); //returns 908
>
> var fNum6 = parseFloat("blue"); //returns NaN

[Read More](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2012-Exploring-Javascript-s-parseInt-And-parseFloat-Functions.htm),
[Read More](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=818)

[Similar Question Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat)

Comment: Nice answer. One request. You wrote "var fNum1 = parseFloat(“1234blue”); //returns 1234.0". But the reality is that 1234.0 == 1234 in javascript since there is only one numeric type. By writing 1234.0 for the parseFloat result and 1234 for the parseInt result you imply that there is a difference between the two results, when in fact there isn't.

Comment: parseFloat(“0xA”); does not return NaN, at least in my test. It returns 0 because it parses 0 and stops at the x.

Answer (score 12):

First of all only `parseInt` accepts second argument. It's called radix. It represents numeral system to be used. In example you can convert number into binary or hexadecimal code.

`parseFloat` only accepts one argument.