# I'm confusing getting value from <select> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get a value from `<select>` `<option>` tag. Select tag is like this

```
<select name="pref" className="XXXX" onChange={getValue}>
{areaData.map((area, index) => (
  <option key={index} value={area.areaCode}>XXXXX</option>
))}
</select>
```

I gave a number here in value={area.areaCode}

Then, getting value function is like this

```
  const getValue = function (e: any) {
    const areaCodeString = e.target.value
    const areaCodeNumber = e.target.valueAsNumber
    console.log(areaCodeString);
    console.log(areaCodeNumber);
  }
```

but Output said areaCodeString is "1" (string)
and areaCodeNumber is "undefined"
I want to get this value as number but it doesn't work.
How can I get the value as number? I thought e.target.valueAsNumber was only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse it as `Number`.

```
const areaCodeNumber = Number(areaCodeString)
```

Alternatively, you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

**Note:** You don't have `valueAsNumber` property in `e.target`, that's why it gives you `undefined`.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813049/11566161

https://cullenwebservices.com/javascript-numbers-number-parseint-parsefloat/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
const areaCodeNumber = Number(e.target.value)
```