# Check if number exists in a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I have an odd situation, I think...

I am writing some jquery/javascript code to validate numbers and I need to check if a given int exists within the entered number.

So for instance if the number I am checking against is 15 and the persons types in a 1, I need to check and see if that 1 exists within the 15, if it does then return true else return false.

I tried .stringOf but that of course only works on strings.

Any thoughts?  Sorry if it is a super simple answer.  Thanks in advance.

So far:

```
var Quantity = parseFloat(entered_value); // 1
var max = 15;
if(max.indexOf(Quantity) >= 0){
    qty = Quantity;
}else{
    qty = max;
}
```

Comment: try converting it to a string to do the check. You can do that easily like this: var maxStr = "" + max, then check maxStr with indexOf

Comment: I would suggest that if you're trying to check for a float value as a substring within a string representation of an integer, then there's a possibility you're going about solving something in a less than ideal way. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve, in context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Quantity = parseFloat(entered_value); // 1
var max = 15;
if(max.toString().indexOf(Quantity.toString()) >= 0){
    qty = Quantity;
}else{
    qty = max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to type out [Reason's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900022/check-if-number-exists-in-a-number#comment24388036_16900022)

```
var num = 1,
    max = 15,
    isSubString = (max+'').indexOf(num) > -1;

if ( isSubString ) {
  // Num is a sub string of max
}
```

Comment: he is trying to test with a float. What if `num = 1.0` or `num = 1.2` ?

Comment: Then it most likely wouldn't be a substring of max. Unless max is also a float then there would be a change.

Comment: but eve if max is a float like `max = 15.0;` num wouldn't be a substring if `num = 1.0`. i think the problem is not that easy ;)

Comment: @mercsen `parseFloat('1.0') === 1`

Comment: why parsing a float as a float? `parseFloat('1.2') === 1.2` ! there must be a reason for using floats instead of int

Comment: A quick read can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat

Comment: haha i know this stuff, it was meant to your post befor the edit ;)

Comment: i guess without knowing the reason he wants to check this its not possible to give the correct answer......