# parseInt behaving different in IE and chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

i have parseInt function.

for 010 as input :

output in IE : 8
output in chrome and firefox: 10

for 099 as input:

output in IE : 0
output in chrome and firefox: 99

Could someone plz help me understand this different behaviour in the browsers.. 
issue is in IE and it is working as expected in chrome and firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There were no suggestions popping up when you asked this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parseint+leading+0

Answer (score 5):

Actually I would argue IE is doing things correctly*** here . `parseInt` for a string starting with a `0` is treated as *octal* input.

To fix the problem, specify the base (in this case, you want decimal - `10`):

```
num = parseInt(str, 10);
```

---

*** In this case "correctly" really means "traditionally". The specification has actually changed.
[Technically, a string starting with `0` can be treated as *either* octal OR decimal, depending on the implementor's whim, where decimal is *now* preferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is `undefined` or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input `string` begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason **always specify a radix when using parseInt**.