# Why am I getting a concatenated value in this loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  making a UI in this link [pluker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gkjWUnMUyER6dAbTcfms?p=preview)
using the following code for a function:

```
function span1(left1, width, id, color11) {

    if (id == 1) {
        var sum = 0;
        if (sum < width)
            sum = width;

        width5 = left1 + sum;
        console.log(width);
    } else if (id == 2) {
        var sum2 = 0;
        left1 = width5;
        if (sum2 < width)
            sum2 = width;

        width1 = left1 + sum2;
    } else if (id == 3) {
        var sum1 = 0;
        if (sum1 < width)
            sum1 = width;
        left1 = width1;
        width2 = sum1 + left1;

    } else if (id == 4) {
        left1 = width2;
        width3 = left1 + width;
    } else {
        left1 = width3;
    }
```

When the id is changing form 1 to 2 its giving my left1 value as 6620 which is concatenation of left1=66 and width=20. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need to use  parseFloat(string)  or parseInt(string)

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly i should do it just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`

```
function span1(left1, width, id, color11) {
   left1 = parseInt(left1 , 10);
   width = parseInt(width , 10);
   // So on ....
```

or you can use parseFloat()  up to what you need .. you can read [Behavior difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat)

Comment: @deepak glad to hear that .. Good Luck :)

Comment: You should be careful to always use both arguments with parseInt, so in this case you likely want `parseInt(left1,10)` for example. Without doing so, you will get erroneous values if the value passed should ever start with a zero.

Comment: @deepak updated answer with ,10   please read Chris comment and the url I refer to in the answer .. finally .. don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef:can you please tell me why 10 is used there

Comment: @deepak click on the link I sent in my answer .. and take a look at last answer on it