# html input not return the correct value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I spend all night just to play with this code but I have no idea why it's not return the correct statement :

```
<input id="price_item" discount="10" more_order="20" type="text" name="co-price-item" value="0" onChange="selection()"/>

function selection(){   

var discount    =  $('#price_item').attr('discount'); 
var more_order  =  $('#price_item').attr('more_order');                                
var input_value =  $('#price_item').val();

if(input_value > more_order) {
            alert('yes : '+input_value+' > '+more_order);   
            }else{
            alert('no : '+input_value+' < '+more_order);                
            }
    }
```

what is wrong with the code caused it already return yes by entering input value started from 3. I hope it return yes if above 20.

I have tried to use

```
var input_value =  document.getElementById("price_item").value;
```

but still got the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use parseFloat() or parseInt();

```
var discount    =  parseInt($('#price_item').attr('discount')  , 10); 
var more_order  =  parseInt($('#price_item').attr('more_order')  , 10);                                
var input_value =  parseInt($('#price_item').val()  , 10);
```

[Behavior difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528433/behavior-difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat)

Comment: My God... you were right. It works. So simple for you. Actually I have tried this method, but without (,10) at the end and it's not work. God bless you..

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't valid HTML attributes; in order for your code to be valid HTML5 you need to prepend the custom attributes with `data-`, and then access them via jQuery's [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2):

```
<input id="price_item" data-discount="10" data-more_order="20" type="text" name="co-price-item" value="0" onChange="selection()"/>

function selection() {   

  var discount    =  $('#price_item').data('discount'); 
  var more_order  =  $('#price_item').data('more_order');                                
  var input_value =  $('#price_item').val();

  if (input_value > more_order) {
    alert('yes : '+input_value+' > '+more_order);   
  } else {
    alert('no : '+input_value+' < '+more_order);                
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason this works is because jQuery `.data()` automatically parses attribute values as JSON, so it converts the strings to numbers. It's not because he was using invalid attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This would work when using parseInt like this:

```
var more_order  =  parseInt($('#price_item').attr('more_order'));
```

here is a JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbx5g8t6/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom attributes like `discount` or `more_order` in an `input` tag in HTML. There are some predefined attributes ([See here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp))

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag) post from StackOverflow.

Comment: This isn't the reason his program is failing.

Comment: @Psyringe I appriciate your nice advise. But when the code is working by using Mohamed-Yousef's answer above. What is the compensation we would get by using the attribute?

Comment: It's true that it's not failing. But it's not a correct approach to the solution. As @nathanhleung said, this feature is only available in HTML5, and it has a preceding `data-`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `input_value` and  `more_order` are strings therefore you will have a string comparison made instead of a numeric one.
Convert the values to numeric to get the required comparison.

see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5