# Why does parseInt("014") come out to 12?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

It seems as though leading zeroes should just be ignored when parsing for an Int.  What is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is parsed as an octal number, and not decimal. 
From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

- If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
  (hexadecimal).
- If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight
  (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations
  deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For
  this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
- If the input
  string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

To force it to parse as Decimal, just supply 10 as your second argument (base).

```
var i = parseInt(012,10);
```

Comment: Is there a way to force it to parse as decimal?

Comment: To solve it you need to a radix of 10 read more on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: See my edit, or @Sarfraz's answer

Answer (score 16):

It is parsed as **octal** number, you need to specify **base** too:

```
parseInt("014", 10)   // 14
```

**Quoting:**

> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>     (hexadecimal).
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This
>     feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not
>     support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this reason always
>     specify a radix when using parseInt.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>     (decimal).

---

- [See for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeros make the number octal

Answer (score 1):

It's an octal number

8 + 4 == 12