# Magento date of birth field validation is not working properly

Tags: validation, magento, magento-1.5

In Magento registration page validation is not allowing me to submit the form for some valid date's.

For example :-

```
08/24/1988
MM/DD/YYYY
```

the above date is not working for me.
The field class are

> input-text validate-custom validation-failed

I found js in the source like below

```
var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', false, '%m/%e/%y');
```

where may be the wrong.Can some anyone suggest me.

Mage version : 1.5.1.0

Comment: new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', false, '%m/%e/%y');  doesnt work in Magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is found in `/js/varien/js.js`, line 438.

```
var error = false, day = parseInt(this.day.value) || 0, month = parseInt(this.month.value) || 0, year = parseInt(this.year.value) || 0;
```

Obviously, varien fell for the [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900857/alertparseint09-shows-me-0-why) [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347313/why-does-parseint014-come-out-to-12) [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) [parseInt Bug/Feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003942/961510)

In short, before ES5, all strings starting with `0` are treated as an [octal/base-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number. Since `08` doesn't exist in base-8, `parseInt`-ing it evaluates to `0`.

`parseInt()` happens to take a second optional argument indicating the base it should be using for the interpretation.

```
parseInt('8');      // => 8
parseInt('08');     // => 0
parseInt('08', 10); // => 8
```

So, the solution to your problem is to patch the line mentioned above to read

```
var error = false, day = parseInt(this.day.value, 10) || 0, month = parseInt(this.month.value, 10) || 0, year = parseInt(this.year.value, 10) || 0;
```

Cheers!