# strange javascript error only when value =9 or 8

Tags: javascript, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

well i have this
http://jsfiddle.net/gMDfk/1/
The alert returns 0
The code in jsfiddle works perfect when value is equal to eight or nine..
Wtf is going on here?

Comment: Please don't just link to jsfiddle but paste the code here.

Comment: ok man, i will thing about this tip in my future questiions:P

Comment: Indeed. I used to ask people to do that, but now I just settle on the fact that the OP doesn't want future visitors to get any benefit from the Q&A; my interest falls apart after that realisation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a `, 10` to parseInt:

```
parseInt( val, 10 );
```

which tells JS to treat is as a base-10 number.  By default, anything starting with `0` is treated as an octal, base-8 number.  Since `09` isn't a valid base-8 number, you'll get `0`

Comment: Good answers contain explanations. 12.4k users know that!

Comment: Then you accidentally pressed "submit" _before_ you'd finished writing?

Comment: No, I just decided to write more instead of leaving just the "do this" answer :)

Comment: @cwolves: Draft answers are discouraged. It's not a race!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal -- You've never looked at an answer and thought "I should type more..."?

Comment: @cwolves: I've never written such a non-answer in the first place ;)

Comment: pfft.  My first line alone is sufficient enough an answer in this case -- people need to learn to look up answers sometimes, and that tells them exactly what to look up :)

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing a number with a 0 means it's interpreted as octal by javascript. Try this:

```
alert(parseInt("010")); //shows "8"
```

You can fix it by passing `10` as a second param to `parseInt`, this lets it know you want it parsed in decimal.

```
alert(parseInt("010", 10)); //shows "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Parseint should use radix parameter: parseint (value, radix). In your case, radix is 10. Otherwise, it will take it as octal.

Answer (score 0):

specify the base

```
parseInt(some_id_value,10);
```