# Why does parseInt("09") return 0 but parseInt("07") return 7?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Why does

```
parseInt("09")
```

return `0` but

```
parseInt("07")
```

return `7`?

Comment: Not a big fan of lmgtfy answers, but have you tried googling this exact phrase: "Why does parseInt(09) return 0"?

Comment: So many of the question already answered about parseInt() and using the proper radix.

Comment: It's a javascript gotcha. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) StackOverflow answer for more information

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The base for strings starting with `0` can be octal (when a radix is not specified - and depending on the browser).

You are looking for:

```
parseInt("09", 10)
```

See the documentation for [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal).
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

The comments for the `radix` optional parameter (the second one in my example) says this:

> While this parameter is optional, **always specify** it to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.

Comment: Not true. The default base for `parseInt` is "intelligent guess" as outlined on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt. Even that behavior is subject to different browser quirks.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Yes, answer already corrected and the information from MDN added.

Answer (score 1):

A leading 0 indicated an coal value "020" is 16, "07" is 7, there is no digit "9" in the octal system, hence no conversion!

Use parseInt("09", 10) to get the value 9.