# Why don't work correct (parseInt) for convert string to int?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does parseInt(“09”) return 0 but parseInt(“07”) return 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763362/why-does-parseint09-return-0-but-parseint07-return-7)

I have a string like (10) | (01)

I want convert to int.

I use this code

```
parseInt("10") ----> 10
parseInt("07") ----> 7
```

but when i use this code for (08) , it is convert to (0)

Comment: How could you not see when asking that it was a duplicate ? Did you look at the other questions in the box ?

Comment: Exu, I search a lot but don't find this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If a string begins with 0 the default radix is 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix).

Try specifying the radix explicitly:

```
parseInt("08", 10)
```