# JavaScript setFullYear() Method Returning an incorrect date

Tags: javascript

This morning I noticed a peculiar issue with the JavaScript setFullYear method.

When using the method like so:

```
d.setFullYear(2012,2,8);
```

The correct value is returned:

```
Thu Mar 08 2012 10:30:04 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

However if I use the parseInt method to return the integers, the date returned is incorrect:

```
d.setFullYear(parseInt("2012"), parseInt("02"), parseInt("08"));
```

returns:

```
Wed Feb 29 2012 10:31:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

It appears that the parseInt method is returning the incorrect values, but when I test it:

`document.write(parseInt("2"));`

Then the correct value is returned (2)

A working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rXByJ/

Does the problem lie with parseInt or with setFullYear?

Comment: Very good question. What a pitfall!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `parseInt('08')` is `0`. This works:

```
d.setFullYear(parseInt("2012"), parseInt("02"), 8);
```

> Both parseInt('08') and parseInt('09') return zero because the
>   function tries to determine the correct base for the numerical system
>   used. In Javascript numbers starting with zero are considered octal
>   and there's no 08 or 09 in octal, hence the problem.

http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/issues-parseint-javascript

Solution is to use the second parameter:

```
parseInt('08', 10)
```

Or

```
Number('08')
```

Also see [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Comment: Number needs quotes around the 08. Be warned, Number('08.789') will produce 8.789 as its output. If you really want an integer, don't use Number

Comment: Brilliant! I hadn't though that parseInt("8") and parseInt("08") could be different, but then I don't come up against octal bases every day...

Answer (score 2):

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) on stackoverflow has a very detailed explanation on why one should use parseInt with a `base` or `radix`

Answer (score 1):

yes thats true parseInt('08') will return 0 instead of 8 because it takes 08 as octal number and converts into 0 so you should use parseInt('08', 10) where second parameter specifies base for conversion, that is 10 for decimal

**so in short always specify base when using parseInt :)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are Ok with overriding `Date.prototype.setFullYear()` function so that it will return a date object instead of milliseconds you can do this.

```
Date.prototype.setFullYear = (function(ref){
   return function(val){ 
      return new Date(ref.bind(this)(val));
  }
})(Date.prototype.setFullYear)
```