# What's wrong with this javascript date parsing? Why does js hate the number 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, date

I've got an object containing dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I'm extracting the various year, month and day integers so I can send them to a different `API`.

Here's an example of my method, using `substr()`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/AppSynergy/tELsw/

OK, it works. OH NO! - it doesn't - not quite.. What's wrong with the 3rd element, where the "08" in 8th April decides to be 0 instead?

If I change "08" to another integer e.g. "03", it's fine. But "08" causes issues..

This one is driving me crazy -- what's wrong?

If you can spot it, you deserve ice-cream.

Comment: Try having a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug

Comment: `08` is parsed as an octal, instead of decimal. This is why we should use the radix with parseInt()`.

Comment: Interesting to note that IE9 is the only browser I tested that follows the [ES5.1 spec correctly](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) and `parseInt("08")` results in `8`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`08` is considered as an (invalid) [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal by default.

You have to explicitly specify the radix in your call to [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in order for this token to be considered as a decimal (base 10) number:

```
$("#debug").append(parseInt(date.substr(5, 2), 10) + " / ");
```

Comment: OMG.. octal default? I would **never** have thought of that! Adding the specific base of 10 solves it perfectly - thanks Frédéric and others that commented!  - A

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `parseInt` with radix/base of `10` since preceding `0` converts your number in octal notation.

```
parseInt(yourNum, 10);
```

Because of that reason, it turns out that you should ALWAYS specify base when using `parseInt` unless you are not working on base `10` numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If string begins with "0", javascript will think the radix is eight (octal).

You need to tell javascript to parse the string by base of 10.

```
$.each(testData, function(i, val) {
    // sort out the date format
    var date = val.trim();
    $('#debug').append(date+' ==><br />');
    $('#debug').append(parseInt(date.substr(0, 4), 10)+' / ');
    $('#debug').append(parseInt(date.substr(5, 2), 10)+' / ');
    $('#debug').append(parseInt(date.substr(8, 2), 10)+'<br /><br />');
});
```