# Validate number in jquery

Tags: javascript, validation

I try to check non negative number in jquery.If other then number my function works but for zero and non negative number its doesn't work.Here is my sample fiddle.
[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AvZJ8/4/)
Unable to find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: This has little to do with *jQuery*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VvsW3/) (NOTE: Error messages are OP's own)

```
$('#txtNumber').keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val(), error ="";
    $('#lblIntegerError').remove();
    if (isNaN(val)) error = "Value must be integer value."
    else if (parseInt(val,10) != val || val<= 0) error = "Value must be non negative number and greater than zero";
    else return true;
    $('#txtNumber').after('<label class="Error"  id="lblIntegerError"><br/>'+error+'</label>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Non-negative _and_ greater than zero? You mean _positive_?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isNaN($('#txtColumn').val() <= 0))
```

That's not right..

You need cast the value to an integer since you're checking against an integer

```
var intVal = parseInt($('#txtColumn').val(), 10);  // Or use Number()

if(!isNaN(intVal) || intVal <= 0){
   return false;
}
```

Comment: @Matt Lo : Yes, exactly. Thanks :)

Comment: But that doesn't work if the user enters invalid data after a valid integer. E.g., `parseInt("123.45abcdefg",10)` returns `123`. Also the radix should be specified (second parameter), or `parseInt("0x12")` returns `18` and `parseInt("010")` returns `8`...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Then you would need to specify the base. `parseInt('010',10)` or else use `Number('010')`. `parseInt()` uses base 8 as the default. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug) for more on that.

Comment: I know how `parseInt()` works, and it uses base 10 as the default except where the string starts with `0` or `0x`. But even when you specify the radix it still happily converts a string like "3abc" to the number 3, so for user-entered data `parseInt()` is not enough on its own...

Comment: @nnnnnn: The `~~` double negation hack would apply here, then? And sorry, I didn't mean to teach you how parseInt works. Was just putting it there for the OP's reference. It was wrongly addressed..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#txtNumber').keyup(function() {
    var num = $(this).val();
    num = new Number(num);
    if( !(num > 0) )
        $('#txtNumber').after('<label class="Error"  id="lblIntegerError"><br/>Value must be non negative number and greater than zero.</label>');
});
```

**Note:** The `parseInt()` ignores invalid characters if the first character is numeric but the `Number()` take cares of them also

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtNumber').keyup(function() 
{
    $('#lblIntegerError').remove();
    if (!isNaN(new Number($('#txtNumber').val())))
    {
        if (parseInt($('#txtNumber').val()) <=0) 
        {
              $('#txtNumber').after('<label class="Error"  id="lblIntegerError"><br/>Value must be non negative number and greater than zero.</label>');
            return false;
        }


    }
    else
     {
          $('#txtNumber').after('<label class="Error"  id="lblIntegerError"><br/>Value must be integer value.</label>');
            return false;
        }
});​
```