# why parseInt('08') is giving 0, whereas parseInt('07') is giving 7

Tags: javascript, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

I am working on javascript, and I seem to find this strange, that the javascript function parseInt('08') is returning 0 and parseInt('07') is returning 7.

this behavior seems to be there in Firefox.

parseInt('08') is returning 8 in IE, but 0 in Firefox..

Why? I want parseInt('08') to return 8, as expected and getting in IE.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yeah, I came across this one before.  It is really odd because some browsers interpret this as you wanting to parse it in base 8.  Consider the following article:

http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C85006A6604

basically, you have to tell the parser to use base 10 numbers:

```
parseInt('08', '10');
```

Comment: `parseInt('08', '10');`? Really? Usually we will just do `+"08"`, since adding `+` in front of a String will turn it into Number without any problem.

Comment: @Derik Post hoc ergo propter hoc

Comment: `parseInt` expects a number as second parameter so you should do `parseInt('08', 10)` instead of `parseInt('08', '10')`