# When to use parseInt

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

Which rule do I have to follow when extracting numbers out of DOM and calcluation with them? How does javascript knows that a value is a number or not? Should I always use parseInt?

Given following Code:

HTML

```
<div id="myvalue">5</div>
<div id="withParseInt"></div>
<div id="withoutParseInt"></div>
<div id="withoutParseIntButIncrement"></div>
```

JS & jQuery:

```
var value = $('#myvalue').text();
$('#withParseInt').text(parseInt(value) + 1);
$('#withoutParseInt').text(value + 1);
$('#withoutParseIntButIncrement').text(value++);
```

Gives following output:

```
5
6
51
5
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytxKU/3/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.text()` method will always return a string. Some operators, like the `+` operator, are overloaded to perform both arithmetic and string operations. In the case of strings, it performs concatenation, hence the "51" result.

If you have a string and need to use a non-coercing operator, you will have to use `parseInt` (or some other method of converting to a number).

However, the `*` operator for example implicity performs this coercion, so you wouldn't need the `parseInt` call in that situation (see an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytxKU/6/) for example).

Note that the increment `++` operator *does* coerce its operand, but you've used the postfix operator so it won't have any effect. Use the prefix operator and you can see it working:

```
$('#withoutParseIntButIncrement').text(++value);
```

So, to summarise:

```
// Parses string to number and adds 1
$('#withParseInt').text(parseInt(value) + 1);

// Coerces number 1 to string "1" and concatenates
$('#withoutParseInt').text(value + 1);

// Implicity coerces string to number, but after it's been inserted into the DOM
$('#withoutParseIntButIncrement').text(value++);

// Implicity coerces string to number, before it's been inserted into the DOM
$('#withoutParseIntButIncrement').text(++value);

// Implicity coerces to number
$('#withoutParseIntButMultiply').text(value * 2);
```

---

Side note: it's considered good practice to always pass the second argument (the radix) to `parseInt`. This ensures the number is parsed in the correct base:

```
parseInt(value, 10); // For base 10
```

Comment: That sound reasonable. Sometimes I had some serious problems when calculating with number extracted out of DOM so Icame along to always use parseInt when handling with number. Your answer confirms it. That way I'm on the safe side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786758/why-parseint08-is-giving-0-whereas-parseint07-is-giving-7?rq=1 This question also explains why you should always supply a base due to some odd browser quirks on parsing integers.

Answer (score 7):

One and only rule:

> Every value that you retrieve from the DOM is a string.

Comment: ... and every value you insert back to DOM becomes a string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always use parseInt() or Number() to be on the safe side. Otherwise Javascript will decide what to do with it

- The value itself is a string
- Using operator `+` will concatenate two strings
- Using operator `-` will calculate the numerical difference
- ...

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to use `parseInt` just to be on the safe side, especially as you can supply a second parameter for the numerical system to use.

By the way, in your final example it should be `++value` if you want it to equal 6.