# Weird intParse behavior

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Given this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var noproblem07 = parseInt("07") - 1;
    alert("No problem (07): " + noproblem07);
    var problem08 = parseInt("08") - 1;
    alert("Problem (08): " + problem08);
    var problem09 = parseInt("09") - 1;
    alert("Problem (09): " + problem09);
    var noproblem10 = parseInt("10") - 1;
    alert("No problem (10): " + noproblem10);
</script>
```

Why do "08" and "09" resolve to -1?

Comment: refer to the 2nd parameter for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `parseInt` parses strings with leading zeros as octal. To get around this, use the `radix` argument to `parseInt`:

```
>>> parseInt("08")
0
>>> parseInt("08", 10)
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the browsers you run in it don't implement the specification correctly and try to parse them as octals, resulting in `0`

It works fine in IE9 and safari 6. You can pass a second parameter to make it correct in all browsers:

```
parseInt(x, 10);
```

Comment: They are probably implementing the specification just fine. They are just implementing an *older* specification. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_Removes_Octal_Interpretation

Comment: @kojiro You think chrome and firefox are implementing es3? They implement es5, but incorrectly regarding this issue.

Comment: This is across the board in chrome, firefox and IE9.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think they're implementing. All that matters is that there is a specification for ECMAScript that allows `parseInt` to have this behavior.

Comment: @kojiro That specification is irrelevant because it is not being implemented by the browsers I was referring to but es5 is.