# Why does parseInt(013) return 11?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjWsD/11/) that shows the behavior:

Pretty simple question, any ideas?

Code is just:

```
parseInt(013)
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/850346/27614)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because if your number is starting with '0', then it's considered as octal, thus

```
'013' = 1 * 8 + 3 = 11
```

Answer (score 10):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) expects a **string**. You have provided an [octal](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-number-object), `013`.

**Use:**

```
parseInt('013', 10)
```

**Note:** I would also encourage passing *radix*, for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The number `013` is being interpreted as an octal.  It has nothing to do with `parseInt`; in fact, `var a = 013;` will have `a` be `11`.