# jQuery if do nothing else do something

Tags: jquery, css

I have a snippit to alter the `margin-left` of a node based on a click:

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    var slidewidth = $('#slide_box').attr('width'),
        slideleft = $('#slide_box').attr('margin-left');
    if (slideleft == 0) {
    }
    else {
        $("#slide_box").animate({"margin-left": "+=135px"}, "fast");
    } 
});
```

Now, if `slideleft == 0`, it shouldn't do anything.  But it does.  However, when the `var slidewidth` is calculated, will it return `0` or `0px`?  How would I define that value in the `if` argument?  When I tried `if (slideleft == 0px)` it just killed the script.

Comment: Just to help you in the future. Any easy way of debugging something like this is to use `console.debug` and you could see the value for yourself.

Comment: The title of the post is very unclear. Did you try `if(slideleft == '0px')`

Comment: a quick way to see what slideleft really is would be to either print the variable in your browsers console (firebug for firefox or developer tools in IE) or use a handy window.alert("Slideleft = " + slideleft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using the correct method to get your `width` and `margin-left` values; both are css values not attributes on the element and `.attr()` will only get element attributes (unless you really are setting an attribute on the element with these names which imho could be very confusing in the future). Instead try this:

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    var slidewidth = $('#slide_box').css('width'),
        slideleft = $('#slide_box').css('margin-left'); 
    /* or alternatively:
       var slidewidth = parseInt($('#slide_box').css('width'),10),
        slideleft = parseInt($('#slide_box').css('margin-left'), 10); 
     */
    if (slideleft == '0px' /* with parseInt values you would just need 0 here*/) {
    }
    else {
        $("#slide_box").animate({"margin-left": "+=135px"}, "fast");
    } 
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parseInt values"?

Comment: Sorry I meant to type "with the parseInt values" ie the values that you would get by using the code i have commented under "/* or alternatively..."

Comment: Parseint values are the values you got by parseInt($('#slide_box').css('width'),10)

Comment: .css returns a string "120px" which you can turn into a number through the method "parseInt". So if you use just the value that is returned from .css you would need to use the string "0px" if you parsed that string into an integer you would use 0

Comment: What does the `10` have to do with anything?

Comment: The method parseInt takes two arguments. The first is the value you wish to parse and the second is the radix or the number base you wish to use. This just ensures that you get a base 10 number versus an octal or some other number that you don't wish. In this example it is more a good habit to keep up as you are just looking for 0. There are many discussions on the topic of parsint with/without radix. Start here if you are really interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#slide_box').css('margin-left')` rather than `$('#slide_box').attr('margin-left')` to get the margin and test using `slideleft === '0px'`

Comment: Changing to `.css` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (slideleft === '0px')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `console.log(slidewidth)` to check the output. I'm pretty sure it will be 0px not 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( parseInt(slideleft,10) === 0) {
```

Better to Convert that to a number using `parseInt` .. That way it will solve the ambiguous problem..

**OR** just  `if ( +slideleft === 0) {`