# What is the shortest way of checking if JS value exists?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have this :

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter A"));
var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"));
var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter C"));
```

What  is the *shortest* way to check if a value exists in all 3 variables ?

Doing    `if(a  && b && c)`  is *not* accurate cause `0` is falsy.

*p.s. **a,b,c can be ints or strings**...Also , There must be a trick here...*

for the string example  :

```
var a = (prompt("Enter A"));
var b = (prompt("Enter B"));
var c = (prompt("Enter C"));
```

Comment: How would `a` be a string after a `parseInt`?

Comment: you say they can be ints or strings, but with the `parseInt()`, they will definitely be ints. (or NaNs, I guess)

Comment: @DaveNewton I'll make it clearer in my question

Comment: Something I should mention: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/850341/913097) if you're using the `parseInt()` function.

Comment: @inhan you can count on it. I know this octal problem. ( this problem does _not_ exist with chrome.) only FF and IE.

Comment: What's wrong with `a && b && c` for strings? "0" is not falsy .. or don't you know the types in advance?

Comment: @AlexK. 0 as int is falsy

Comment: Aye but not as a string from a prompt() cant you && if you want 3 strings & isNaN is you want 3 ints?

Comment: @AlexK. try it and put 0 http://jsbin.com/anudex/2/edit

Comment: My point is 0 from parseInt is falsy but "0" from prompt() is not so && is ok if your not using parseInt, if you are using parseInt you can isNaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to categorically confirm whether all of these values is defined, regardless of type, is this:

```
if( (typeof a !== 'undefined') || 
    (typeof b !== 'undefined') || 
    (typeof c !== 'undefined')) { /* ... */ }
```

Unfortunately, shortcuts that rely on truthiness of values and, as you point out, this is not always an acceptable approach.

As Alex K shows, you can do some tricky stuff if you know the type of the variable beforehand, but knowing the type beforehand may require as much code as you avoid in the comparison.

**Edit 1**

Dave Newton pointed out that `prompt` always returns a defined value; it returns `null` if user's press cancel.

Thus, a better approach would be:

```
function isValid(value) {
    return typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null);
}

if( isValid(a) && isValid(b) && isValid(c) ){ /* ... */ }
```

**Edit 2**

Of course, the simplest thing to do is to check for validity before parsing the ints. Since

```
!!""  === false
!!"0" === true
!!0   === false
```

You can use `(a && b & c)` on the string/null that prompt returns and only if they are valid, do your parsing.

Comment: They'll always be defined from a prompt, no? Even if you hit escape it'd be null.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
ok = !isNaN(a+b+c);
```

Comment: Alas, OP just edited with a completely different second case.

Comment: @apsillers I edited now, but wrote it when first publishing.(a,b,c can be also strings). the _edit_ was written now.

Comment: @RoyiNamir But saying "they can also be strings" didn't make any sense given the code. The code is always the defining artifact, since it's what runs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `(!!a && !!b && !!c)`?

AFAIK, unless the value of a **string** variable is empty, `null` or `undefined` it should evaluate to `true`. 0 would also return `false` but I'm writing on behalf of your `prompt()` call since its value would not be of type Number.

Answer (score 0):

Always use:

```
if (typeof( variableName ) != "undefined") {
    //Do something
}
```

Since Javascript uses Json object notation the following code is completely valid:

```
var x = {};

if (x.test == undefined) {
    //Do something
}
```

But if "x" does not exists this produces an error.
There is no way to do this safer in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to check if a set of variables has valid, acceptable values is to create a helper function according to your specification which accepts a variable number of arguments. In this example, this function will return false if an argument is undefined, null, or a NaN number. Strings will return true for `isNaN`, so we check if the argument's type is a number before checking if it is NaN.

```
function isValid() {
    var i, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    for(i = 0; i < args.length; i += 1) {
        if( typeof args[i] === 'undefined' || args[i] === null
        || (typeof args[i] === 'number' && isNaN(args[i]))
        ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Utilize it like so:

```
if( isValid(a, b, c) ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values can only be strings or numbers, you can use:

```js
var valid = ('' + a) && ('' + b) && ('' + c); //always convert into string
```

Here's also a fancy but relatively short one, which deals with `undefined`, `null` and empty string:

```js
var valid = [a].join() && [b].join() && [c].join();
```

In `Array.prototype.join()`, when an element is `undefined` or `null` it will be converted into an empty string.

But it's neither elegant nor efficient. :(