# Javascript calculation not correct

Tags: javascript

i have a weird problem in my javascript, take a look at my code below:

```
dateParts = document.getElementById('date').value.split('/');
newDays = 14;
year = dateParts[2];
month = parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1;
day = parseInt(dateParts[0]) + parseInt(newDays);
alert(dateParts[0]+" + "+newDays+" = "+day);
```

and assume `document.getElementById('date') = 07/01/2013`

the calculation will give a correct result = `07 + 14 = 21`

the calculation work fine at all date, except for `08/01/2013` / `09/01/2013`

which the result is `08 + 14 = 14`, any idea whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your numbers are treated as octals, since you haven't used [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) within `parseInt()`s. You need to adjust your `parseInt()`s like this:

```
month = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1;
day = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10) + parseInt(newDays, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

The leading `0` in `08` and `09` is causing JavaScript to assume the number is octal. Since those are not valid octal values, it treats them as 0. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior) for more details.

You should always use a radix when calling `parseInt` to avoid this problem.

Comment: thanks for the link, never heard about the octal in javascript before

Answer (score 1):

the function is The parseInt(str, redix), if the value in the parseInt start with 0, it is assumed the radix is 8 so '09', '08' is  invalid and the function returns 0. You need to call the function like parseInt('08', 10) to get the correct value.