# Javascript variable with leading zeroes

Tags: javascript, leading-zero

Javascript behaves differently with values having leading zeroes.
alert(b) - prints different value.

```
var a = 67116;
var b = 00015;
alert(a);
alert(b);
```

I am more interested to know What conversion is applied here by javascript inside alert(b) ?
(If i have them in double quotes. They work fine.)

Comment: Yeah, what the hell is going on here: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/4qsvQ/

Comment: If they are in quotes, it is a string and will be read literally.

Comment: @Kris , your nickname is the same of my exgf, i'm depressed now :/ ... is that weird?

Comment: May be you are too weird...i better say, you are her EX.
i rather place you in variable b..that will give you new decimal life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var b = 00015
```

is an octal number

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior) for solution

Comment: http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/octal-to-decimal/

Comment: This has nothing to do with "weak typing"

Answer (score 3):

A leading `0` makes the value an octal literal, so the value you put will be interpreted as a base 8 integer.

In other words, `015` will be equivalent to `parseInt('15', 8)`.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers said, the leading zeroes make the number an octal literal. The decimal representation of the octal "15" is "13".

Note that there is no reason to use leading zeroes on number literals unless you really really want them to be interpreted as octals. I mean, don't use `var b = 00015`. If you're getting that value from user input, then it will be a string (i.e. `"00015"`), and you can convert to a decimal number with `parseInt`:

```
var b = "00015"; // or var b = document.getElementById('some_input').value
var numB = parseInt(b, 10); // 15
```