# JavaScript variable having decimals with preceding zero prints wrong on Firebug

Tags: javascript, variables

It might be a dumb question, today I was playing with Firebug,

I typed:

```
var test = 100011;
console.log(test);
```

I get out put as `100011` which is correct

But when I type the following code:

```
var test = 0100011;
console.log(test);
```

I get `4097`

Why am I getting 4097?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript variable with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114258/javascript-variable-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: Thank you, thats exact question.. I will remove mine to remove duplicate from SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preceding 0 causes the number to be interpreted in octal.

A preceding 0x causes the number to be interpreted in hexadecimal.

Comment: You may want to look in to using strict mode. It flags octal numbers as an error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode