# Insert html if div contains number over 'x'

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a free delivery banner if the price of a product is over £50.

My attempt:

```
$(function() {

if( $('.num').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 50.00;})) {

    $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'freeDelivery').appendTo('.imgoffer');
$('#freeDelivery').append('<img id="freeDeliveryImage" alt="Free delivery on this item" src="https://location_of_image.png" width="70" height="70">');

    }   
});
```

My code inserts the free delivery element even if the amount isn't over 'x'. Any suggestions?

Comment: remember to always use radix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter()` returns a jQuery object(even if the collection is empty) and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, you should read the `.length` property of the returned object.

```
if ( $('.num').filter(function() { return [condition] }).length ) {
    ... 
}
```

Also note that you should specify the radix for the [`.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method, otherwise you will get unexpected results.

```
parseInt(str, radix);
```