# JavaScript input value issue

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't work as expected:

```
function sum(x,y){
    return x + y;
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(e)
{

    //do someting
    e.stopPropagation();

    var value1 = document.getElementById('v1').value,
    value2 = document.getElementById('v2').value;

    var newSum = sum(value1, value2);
    console.log(newSum);

}
```

There is something wrong with the values being picked up. It should return the sum and not "1+2=12"

Comment: @Jahnux73 it's better to use `parseInt()` to preserve data integrity.

Comment: `1 + 2` may equal `3`, but `'1' + '2'` equals `'12'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
return x + y;
```

to

```
return parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
```

You have to convert the values to numbers first, before adding them. If the numbers are floats, you can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

**Edit** As suggested by RGraham in the comments, its always better to pass the radix (check `parseInt`'s doc) explicitly. So, the code becomes

```
return parseInt(x, 10) + parseInt(y, 10);
```

Comment: Don't forget to [specify the radix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)! `parseInt(x, 10);`

Comment: @RGraham Mentioned that in an edit :)

Answer (score 2):

For more accuracy:

```
  function sum(x,y){    
     return parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your value to an int as all values are passed as string in javascript.

```
value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('v1').value, 10);
value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('v2').value, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

**[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

Syntax

var num = parseInt(string, radix);

Parameters

**string**
    The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to one. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored.

**radix**
    An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

```
  function sum(x,y){

           return parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10);
        }
```