# How to handle hours difference between times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery hours range picker and I am not using 'am' & 'pm' notation. I prefer 24h. I need to calculate the hours difference between selected hours.

User selects `'09:00' & '12:00' -> 3 hours`

My problem is with if he selects `'20:00' & '00:00' -> must be 4` hours but gives negative. Alternatively; `'23:00' & '02:00' -> negative`

Should I take abs? or any other way?

Comment: `if hoursA > hoursB` add 24 hours to B, then subtract A - assuming there will only be a single day between the dates

Comment: if hours are negative, add 24 to first value

Comment: @PraveenTiwari that would give `21` hours for the OPs last example

Comment: you are right @Rory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work out time difference between two times on a 24 hour clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967214/how-to-work-out-time-difference-between-two-times-on-a-24-hour-clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add if check to the difference you get and if it's negative add 24 hours to it

```
var diff = function(a,b) {
  var difference = b - a;
  if (difference < 0) {
    return difference + 24;
  } else {
    return difference;
  }
}
```

Of course you will need to parse your time first. Here is a fiddle with alerts instead of returns. But this is the easiest way i guess, but mb not the best one
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk0znkww/)

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but you have missed a `)` and you don't return anything outside of the `if` statement. Also some description of the problem and why this fixes it would help to educate the OP and any future visitors to this question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use modulo. Unfortunately Javascript's modulo is wrong.

```js
Number.prototype.mod = function(n) {
    return ((this % n) + n) % n;
};

console.log((0 - 20).mod(24));
```