# Addition of attributes backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
homeTeam = this.collection.where({teamName: 'Bulls'});

var totalPoints = [];
_.each(homeTeam, function(team) {
    var total = team.get('points');
    totalPoints.push(total);
});

var sum = _.reduce(totalPoints, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

In the above I am trying to get the total amount of points the home team has, by iterating through that attribute, then pushing those values into an array. Finally I am using underscore.js's `_.reduce` method, but I am not getting the right number in the console.

The actual points are 10,12,18,3,0,0 and when I `console.log(sum)` I get 0101218300, so it turns all those seperate numbers into one gigantic number not by adding the sum but just combining them.

So obviously I am missing something, hopefully there is a better way to add attributes than the way I am doing it.

Comment: Are you passing in the numbers as strings?  That would result in the strings simply being concatenated, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah I am looking at underscore.js `toArray` I am just now seeing this.

Comment: So it looks like I need to rephrase, how do I make sure that it passes as an array, not string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because total points is stored as an array of string. try

```
.each(homeTeam, function(team) {
    //convert the string to int
    var total = parseInt(team.get('points'),10);
    totalPoints.push(total);
});
```

Comment: I removed the 10 and it worked the same, is it vital to have it there, because I have not seen that yet, and don't understand why it's there.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior

Comment: You should really think twice before removing the second argument 10 as it's really important.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix

Comment: Okay thats all I wanted to hear, thanks for the links!