# How can I parse String to Int in an Angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A number string '5'

```
var num_str = '5';
```

How can I parseInt and let below answers correct at the same time?

```
{{num_str + 1}}  // 6
{{num_str - 1}}  // 4
```

parseInt can't be used in an Angular expression,

```
{{parseInt(num_str) - 1}}
```

number filter can't do add and minus,

```
{{num_str - 1 | number}}
```

If anyone have useful suggestion, I will very appreciate of you

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom filter they're fairly easy to write just a function that takes the input and returns the output.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$scope.num_str = parseInt(num_str, 10);  // parseInt with radix
```

Comment: Remember in javascript to always specify the radix for parseInt   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior

Answer (score 80):

I prefer to use an angular filter.

```
app.filter('num', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return parseInt(input, 10);
    };
});
```

then you can use this in the dom:

```
{{'10'|num}}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnJc9/).

Hope this helped!

Comment: Useful and in the AngularJs way. Thanks!

Comment: very nice solution!

Comment: Does not work if you want to +1 or -1 as the question asked.

Answer (score 58):

You can try:

```
{{ 1 * num_str + 1 }}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z32fP/

Comment: Please don't ever add little hacks like this into a real code base.

Comment: This won't work if the number is in the thousands and the string has a comma in it. This could turn 1000 into a number but not 1,000

Comment: I agree that this is a hack, but this looks like the only working solution

Answer (score 24):

Another option would be:

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

Then you could do this like you wanted:

```
{{parseInt(num_str)-1}}
```

This is because angular expressions don't have access to the `window`, only to `scope`.

Also, with the number filter, wrapping your expression in parentheses works:

```
{{(num_str-1) | number}}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEcJ4a08X0FyIYCQe2Yg?p=preview)

Comment: Angular's built in | number filter is the way to go in most cases.

Answer (score 20):

```
{{ num_str - 0 }}
```

...works for me.

Comment: Genius solution. When num_str = '' Null string this still works. I thought I would get a NaN but works awesome!

Comment: Nice solution. Works for null and blank string; this is just Javascript behavior so it should work permanently. Only gets NaN for undefined or the string is not a valid number.

Comment: Nice one, funny that {{ num_str + 1 }} doesn't work -.-

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me.

But this did:

```
{{ (num1_str * 1) + (num2_str * 1) }}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use javascript [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) method to parse it to an number,

```
var num=Number (num_str);
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is a discussion about angularjs, not pure javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Besides {{ 1 * num_str + 1}}
You can also try like this(minus first):

```
{{ num_str - 0 + 1}}
```

But the it's very fragile, if num_str contains letters, then it will fail. So better should try writing a filter as @hassassin said, or preprocess the data right after initiating it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pipe and use it wherever you want in your system.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 @Pipe({
     // tslint:disable-next-line:pipe-naming
     name: 'toNumber',
     pure: false }) export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform { 
     public transform(items: any): any {
         if (!items) {
             return 0;
         }
         return parseInt(items, 10);
     } }
```

In the HTML

```
{{ attr.text | toNumber }}
```

Remember to declare this Pipe to be accessfull in your modules file.

Answer (score 1):

**Use in component.ts file**

```
convertStringToInt(str){ 
  var Num = parseInt(str); 
  return Num;
}
```

**Use in component.html**

```
convertStringToInt("2.4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions mentioned above and none of them worked for me.  I used JSON.parse and it worked:

```
$http.get('/api/getAdPolling')
  .success(function (data) {
    console.log('success: ' + data.length);

    if (JSON.stringify(data) != "not found") {
        $scope.adPoll = JSON.parse(data);
    }
})
  .error(function (data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really great but a funny hack:
You can -- instead of +

```
{{num_str -- 1 }}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  {{'1'--1}}
</div>
```